# Ruby idiom for do_two_simple_things if something_is_true

Tags: ruby

For instance, this takes 4 lines which is too much space for such a simple operation:

```
if something_is_true
  puts 'error'
  return
end
```

this one is a one-liner but looks awkward.

```
if something_is_true; puts 'error'; return; end
```

Can we do something like

```
# it would be great if this would work because it is short and readable
puts 'error' and return if something_is_true
```

Comment: The idiom is to do it the first way. One-line conditionals are meant for doing, well, *one* thing. I've never seen it otherwise.

Comment: I've seen many people wrote `render :status => 404
 and return if params[:something].blank?`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with @NedBatchelder that your original code is probably best. Others have pointed out that in your particular example, you can use `return puts 'error'`.

Still, for the sake of learning, you *can* group multiple statements with parentheses, and therefore use a small number of statements in places where you could otherwise use only one.  You said:

```
# it would be great if this would work because it is short and readable
puts 'error' and return if something_is_true
```

You can do this with:

```
(puts 'error'; return) if something_is_true
```

Comment: This one ANSWERS my question.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure why you think space is at such a premium that your original code is "too much."  Give your code room to breathe, and let it take the space it needs.  Getting too tricky in order to "save space" is a false economy.  The most important thing is that your code be readable and understandable.  Your original code looks great to me.

Comment: Hi, Ned. I do not agree with you. Saving more space while maintaining readability means that you can fit more code in your eye, the same reason why rubyists write short functions, why ruby supports `do_one_simple_thing if something_is true` syntax, why ruby's convention is to use 2 spaces instead of 4 space for indentation, why some people prefer python's choice of using indentation instead of `}` or `end`.

Comment: Sure, shorter is better, but that doesn't mean you can reasonably make it shorter than the four lines you have.  More code fitting in your eye isn't better if the code is confusing because of tricks.

Comment: `puts 'error' and return if something_is_true` is not confusing if ruby supports this kind of construct. I am just a little bit surprised to learn that ruby - a language emphasizes readability in some sense - does not have this syntax sugar.

Comment: @powerboy There's no syntactic sugar there, and the statement you have *is* valid Ruby, it just doesn't do what you expect it to because of how `and` works. And since what you're trying to do is completely different than that, it would be confusing.

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of awful but I think it will work because puts returns nil:

```
puts 'error' || return if something_else
```

Comment: This works but it IS awful and it relies on the fact that `puts` returns nil which is - as some people (me included) would say - a trick.

Comment: This is also not so great because you should be using `or`.

Answer (score 1):

In this specific case, `return` without a value will return `nil`; as this happens to also be the return value of `puts`, you can get the same effect with just:

```
return puts "error" if something_else
```

Answer (score 0):

Someday you will probably care less about how many cycles you can spend in a single line of code.  I would use the `if-end` block because it is simple, clear, and... you know, that's what it's there for.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend never to use `;` to join statements, it tends to be unreadable. But still there are other approaches, two ideas: first one, join `error(msg, return_value = nil)` and `return`:

```
return(error("Message")) if something_is_true

return(error("Message", value_to_be_returned)) if something_is_true
```

Second one, in Ruby it's idiomatic to signal problems using exceptions, so you can write this perfectly idiomatic one-liner:

```
raise MyException.new("human explanation of the error") if condition
```

The same idea used in an assignment:

```
link = doc.at_css(".content a.link") or raise MyException.new("msg")
```